# Trouble in dual booting windows 7 and windows 8

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, boot

I installed Windows 7 and Windows 8 on the same partition of my hard disk.I had first installed Windows 7 and after that I installed Windows 8.But after installing windows 8 on the boot-list I didn't find windows 7 on the boot-menu and it directly starts and goes into windows 8.So I used **bootrec.exe /rebuildMbr** To rebuild MBR after that I found windows 7 on Boot-menu of windows 8.Now when i entered into windows 7 I had following problems

```
1. The logon screen shows "Preparing your Desktop" before showing Desktop.

2. The desktop screen goes black and there was not any task bar.
```

I can access task manager but there were not any process **explorer.exe**. When I tried to start **explorer.exe** a window appears and I get another error i.e

```
3."Ordinal not found" The ordinal 2521 cannot be located in dynamic link library user32.dll.
```

when i press ok on that a typical windows 98 like taskbar opens but the desktop is still black and it gives me message.

```
4."You have been logged with temporary profile"
   you cannot access your files and files created in this profile will be
   deleted when you log off. To fix this log off and try logging on later.
   please see the event log for details or contact your system administrator.
```

As said above when I log off or log on again the same process repeats itself again and again. when I tried to open computer I get another Error i.e

```
 5. "Explorer.exe" No such interface supported.
```

I am confused and I don't know really how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having 2 OS on the same partition can become several problems, and your system will be slow. 
It constantly conflicts, as they both appear in the registry,document and settings, Back up the data that you need -Have all the drivers and legal licensed copy of Windows( I presume) and do a fresh installation. This is ultimately the best option, and your machine will run faster and you would have recovered all your initial drivespace that the 2nd OS were taking up.
Let this be a learning experience - 2 OS on the same partition is the same as 2 woman in the same kitchen - they are constantly in conflict to be in charge

Comment: Means we cant put two OS on same partition right.Cant there is anyway except formatting my partition i don't want windows-8 it is running healthy I want my windows-7 back.

Comment: Use the 'bootrec' in System Recovery Options !

Comment: @ArruneshSingh - You are going to have to start over.